# I want to decompress a string like ab2cd3 to ababcdababcdababcd

Tags: java

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
>       at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
>       at start.compress.main(compress.java:16)

I;m getting this error my code:

```
package start;
import java.util.*;

public class compress {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j;
        Scanner v = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = v.next();
        String sum = "";
        for(i = 0;i < s.length(); i++) {
            int k = s.charAt(i);
            if(k >= 48 && k <= 57) {
                for(j = 1;j < k; j++)
                    sum = sum + s.substring(0, i);
            }

            String c = k - 48 + "";
            s = s.replaceFirst(c, sum);
        }

        System.out.println(s);
        v.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add some explanation on how `ab2cd3` is expanded.

Comment: Will the numbers ever be higher than 9?

Comment: i want to replace kth no. encountered at ith index with a substring from 0 to i i.e ab2cd3 for first iteration i want 2 to be replaced by ab

Comment: no its just a single digit no.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the rest of the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `increment` in your `for(j=1; j<k; i++)` to `for(j=49; j<k;j++)`. However, this itself will not produce the expected result. You will need to clear the `sum` variable in each of the outer iteration. The below code will give the expected result

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,j;
    Scanner v=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=v.next();

    for(i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
        String sum = "";
        int k=s.charAt(i);
        if(k>=48 && k<=57)
        {
            for(j=49;j<k;j++)
                sum=sum+s.substring(0,i);
        }
        String c=k-48+"";
        s=s.replaceFirst(c,sum);
    }

    System.out.println(s);
    v.close();

}
```

`Input: ab2cd3`
`Output: ababcdababcdababcd`

Comment: Input: "ab2c22"  Output: "ababcababcababcababc"?  Is this what is expected?  I would have thought the output was supposed to be "ababccababcc"

Comment: @Shar1er80 I think the expansion should be worked from the left to the right. At first while parsing the input and come across `2`, you are supposed to replace `ab2cd3` with whatever was to the number's left such that the resulting string will have the preceding string that many times, that is, `ababcd3`. And when you come across `3` later on, you replace `3` by `3-1` times whatever is to its left, that it, `ababcd` resulting in `ababcdababcdababcd`.

Comment: @Shar1er80 since the OP dint provide any explanation on the expansion, that is what I assumed since it is in the title

Comment: OIC, I understand your algorithm now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are doing

```
     for(j=1;j<k;i++)
```

which is equivalent to

```
     while(j<k){
         i++;
         //some code which does not increment j and goes in to infinite loop
     }
```

that's why you are getting exception at

```
     sum=sum+s.substring(0,i); // your i is increasing infinitely
```

It should be

```
      for(j=1;j<k;j++)
```

**UPDATE** I just realised that your code does not work at all.

because of your following code:

```
       int k=s.charAt(i);
       if(k>=48 && k<=57)  
        {
            for(j=1;j<k;j++)
                sum=sum+s.substring(0,i);
            }
            String c=k-48+"";
            s=s.replaceFirst(c,sum);

        }
```

when you read `a`, your `k` will be 97 and you will loop for 97 times.
Change your loop to

```
          for(j=49;j<k;j++)
                sum=sum+s.substring(0,i);
```

it will work fine.

Comment: @ShivangiAwasthi you are getting the exception or you are getting the wrong output?

Comment: @karthik the exception was  for some different reasons .

Comment: @karthik  _" I just realised that your code does not work at all even with suggestion in the accepted solution"_ I never suggested anything.I just pointed out the root of cause.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking with

```
for(j=1;j<k;i++)
sum=sum+s.substring(0,i);
```

It will run from 1 to the characters ASCII value say above 48.But clearly the input string have no index close to that range-OutOfBonds.Also the exception will exist if you change

```
for(j=1;j<k;i++)
sum=sum+s.substring(0,i);
```

to

```
for(j=1;j<k;j++)
sum=sum+s.substring(0,j);
```

As stated in the other answer, but the exception is beacuse of your `j` which runs till ASCII of current char.

Comment: This produces the expected output, or just gets rid of the exception?

Comment: @Shar1er80 It tells the root of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your question that the if the last character of your `String` is a digit, it indicates how many times the remaining string will repeat.  After each set of characters "can" be a digit indicating how many times that set of characters repeat.

For example,

- "ab2" ==> "abab"
- "ab2c2" ==> "ababcababc"
- "ab2c22" ==> "ababccababcc"
- "ab2cd3" ==> "ababcdababcdababcd"

Having said that, extract the last character from the string and check if its a digit which will control how many times the entire decompressed `String` repeats and remove the last character from the String.

Then using `regex` examine the remainder of the string for patterns of `"[a-zA-Z]+\\d?"` (One or more letters, possibly followed by a digit).  If there is a digit at the end of the pattern that controls how many times to decompress the letter pattern into the result.

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> inputs = new ArrayList() {
        {
            add("ab2");
            add("ab2c2");
            add("ab2c22");
            add("ab2cd3");
        }
    };

    for (String input : inputs) {
        char lastCharacter = input.charAt(input.length() - 1);
        int outerLoop = 1;

        // If the last character is a digit set it to the outer loop and
        // remove it from the string
        if ('0' <= lastCharacter && lastCharacter <= '9') {
            outerLoop = lastCharacter - 48;
            // Remove the last digit character
            input = input.substring(0, input.length() - 1);
        }

        // Build the decompressed string
        StringBuilder decompressed = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < outerLoop; i++) {
            // Find patterns, if any that have letters followed by a number
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+\\d?").matcher(input);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                String match = matcher.group();

                // Check if the last character of the pattern is a number
                // to control how many times to repeat this pattern in the 
                // decompressed string
                lastCharacter = match.charAt(match.length() - 1);
                int innerLoop = 1;
                if ('0' <= lastCharacter && lastCharacter <= '9') {
                    innerLoop = lastCharacter - 48;
                    // Remove the last digit character
                    match = match.substring(0, match.length() - 1);
                }

                // Decompress the pattern
                for (int j = 0; j < innerLoop; j++) {
                    decompressed.append(match);
                }
            }
        }

        // Display decompressed results
        System.out.println(decompressed);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
abab
ababcababc
ababccababcc
ababcdababcdababcd
```